# How do I move all tables from one Postgres schema to another

Tags: postgresql, schema, alter-table

I want to move all tables from schema `xyz` to the default schema `public`.

I can move individual tables with

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name
    SET SCHEMA public;
```

And I can get all tables with

```sql
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='xyz'
```

Is there any way to combine these two together?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use PL/pgSQL in a `DO` statement:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   p_table regclass;
BEGIN
   SET LOCAL search_path='xyz';
   FOR p_table IN
      SELECT oid FROM pg_class
      WHERE relnamespace = 'xyz'::regnamespace
        AND relkind = 'r'
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %s SET SCHEMA public', p_table);
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

Comment: I am getting this Error `Cannot move an owned sequence into another schema`

Comment: Oops, I forgot the `relkind` check. Fixed.

Comment: relation "table_name" does not exist

Comment: Either it is a quote issue or because missing schema name as prepend. like xyz.table_name. Or both ?

Comment: Can't be, I'd say. What is the failing SQL statement (real names please). It should not matter, but if you want the schema name included always, you can add `SET search_path = pg_catalog;` right after the `BEGIN`.

Comment: SET search_path='xyz' did the trick, thanks

Comment: Hm, shouldn't have been necessary. But if it worked for you, great.

Comment: Thank you. It just worked. I moved a private schema to public. I was using pgloader and it silently added to private. Was not showing in table.

Answer (score 5):

An improved version of [Laurenz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/237854/72070)'s Answer;

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql
$body$
DECLARE
   l_old_schema NAME = 'old_schema';
   l_new_schema NAME = 'new_schema';
   l_sql TEXT;
BEGIN
  FOR l_sql IN
    SELECT 
        format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I SET SCHEMA %I', n.nspname, c.relname, l_new_schema)
      FROM pg_class c
      JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
      WHERE
        n.nspname = l_old_schema AND
        c.relkind = 'r'
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'appliying %', l_sql;
    EXECUTE l_sql;
  END LOOP;
END;
$body$;
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly modified version of [Laurenz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/176905/laurenz-albe)'s Answer

```sql
DO 
$$ DECLARE
   table_record regclass;
BEGIN
  SET LOCAL search_path = xyz;
  FOR table_record IN
   SELECT  table_name  FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='xyz'
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %s SET SCHEMA public',table_record);
  END LOOP;
END; $$
```

Answer (score 1):

--move all tables from schema 'b' to schema 'a':

1. `select 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' SET SCHEMA b' from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'a';`
2. run all altered statements

set search_path = 'a';
-- all alter statements

---

move all functions from schema 'a' to 'b'

1. `select 'ALTER FUNCTION ' || routine_name || ' SET SCHEMA b' from information_schema.routines where routine_type = 'FUNCTION' and specific_schema = 'a'`
2. 

set search_path a;
-- alter statements

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you could just do a

```
alter database pgdb_name set search_path to mysql_dbname, public, $user;
```

as described [here](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/710#issuecomment-356228869)